# Qdockwidget -- floating button on titlebar of qdockwidget

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I am using `QDockWidget` in my GUI and I need to create a slot for the floating button of a `QDockWidget` so that when I click the floating button of a `QDockWidget` it maximize it.

Which signal is emitted when I click floating button on an `QDockWidget` ? I want to trigger a slot where I will make window floating & then maximize it, using this code.

```
ui->dockWidget_2->setFloating(1);
ui->dockWidget_2->showMaximized();
```

Please suggest which signal is emitted when i click float button on a `QDockWidget` ?

Comment: -1 Why didn't you just look in the `signals` section of the `QDockWidget` docs!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#topLevelChanged

```
void QDockWidget::topLevelChanged ( bool topLevel ) [signal]
This signal is emitted when the floating property changes. The topLevel parameter is true if the dock widget is now floating; otherwise it is false.
```

So you can connect it to a slot that maximizes the widget if topLevel is true

Comment: // no need to connect --> if we define --> name of slot as --->on_(object_name)_(signal_name)
    //http://www.qtforum.org/article/20685/connectslotsbyname.html
    // Resizing window
    //http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7815

Comment: Thats still a connect, just qt takes care of it. And ive had problems with it and nested widgets with same nsmes